# Определите максимальное количество идущих подряд символов, среди которых не более одной буквы A. A

Tags: python

Текстовый файл содержит только заглавные буквы латинского алфавита
(ABC. . .Z). Определите максимальное количество идущих подряд символов,
среди которых не более одной буквы A. Не понимаю в чём я ошибся, возможно вообще по другому надо было решать?

```
f = open("24.txt")
st = f.read()
f.close()
cur_len = 0
max_len = 0
for x in st:
    if x == "A":
        cur_len += 1
        if cur_len > max_len:
            max_len = cur_len
    else:
        cur_len = 0
print(max_len)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так, в качестве альтернативного алгоритма...
Разбиваем строку на подстроки по букве "A" и сразу вычисляем их длины. Далее в цикле складываем длины соседних подстрок и берём из этих сумм максимальную. Ну и прибавляем единицу так как сама буква "А" не была включена ни в одну из подстрок. Для исходной строки без букв "А" делается отдельное вычисление *(просто берётся длина всей строки)*.

```
with open("24.txt") as f:
    s = f.read().strip()

seq = list(map(len, s.split("A")))
result = max(map(sum, zip(seq, seq[1:])))+1 if len(seq) > 1 else len(s)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in st:
    if x == "A":
        cur_len += 1
        if cur_len > max_len:
            max_len = cur_len
    else:
        cur_len = 0
```

вы подсчитываете длину последовательности только, когда у вас буква "А", а в задаче сказано:

> Определите максимальное количество идущих подряд символов, **среди которых не более одной буквы A**.

Так у вас в задаче ошибка или в коде?

Если судить по заданию, то

1. минимум надо `if x != "A":` сделать
2. надо учесть ситуацию вида `'BBABBBAAA'` в которой надо выделить `'BBABBB'`

Comment: В коде, вообще написал не то, что надо для задачи

Comment: тогда зачем код вставили? если не то

Comment: потому что понял это, только после вашего объяснения)